# Update laravel 5.2 -> 5.6 errors on compuser update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Tryting to update my laravel version from 5.2 to 5.6.
Running composer update, show these errors - very not clear to understand what is needed to do:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.6 requires illuminate/support 5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.45], illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.5 requires illuminate/support 5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.45], illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.6 requires illuminate/support 5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.45], illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.2.45].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-cors ^0.8.5 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-cors[v0.8.5, v0.8.6].
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.5",
        "predis/predis": "~1.1@dev",
        "cmgmyr/messenger": "~2.0",
        "kreait/firebase-php": "2.0",
        "brozot/laravel-fcm": "^1.2",
        "minishlink/web-push": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "laravel/homestead": "^3.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate",
            "php artisan jwt:generate"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `composer.json`?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Added

Comment: I think you just need to update `"barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.5",`.  That version only supports up to laravel 5.4.